# Bootstrap 3 not loading glyphicon icons... help :(

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

if you go here:

https://secure.dynawebs.net/_studiolite-dev/studiolite-bs.html

I trippled checked all paths as well as re-downloaded bootstrap 3.

with Chrome or FF you will see the glyphicon on the login page just fine (blue icon next to the StudioLite text).

Do the same with IE 10/11 and nada... I have a feeling maybe it's something to do with the fact I use https:// but I don't get any errors in IE and the path to the CSS is relative so it should work.... been banging my head for couple of hours...

any help is greatly appreciated,

Sean.

Comment: Have you tried updating the version of your font?

Comment: You have several 404 errors pertaining to the fonts in the Chrome console. Make sure you have uploaded ALL of the font files.

Answer (score 0):

Font Awesome doesn't support IE7. There is a little info on work-arounds here:

[Fort Awesome 3.2.1 Git Hub IE 7 Support](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/3.2.1/get-started/#need-ie7)

Answer (score 0):

Well, I ended up adding this to me CSS

@import url("https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-glyphicons.css");

which solved the problem...
What I dont understand is that why this doesnt work:
@import url("https://secure.dynawebs.net/_studiolite-dev/_common/_js/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-glyphicons.css");

as both point to same file, and internally the paths are relative and valid.

I have a feeling IE10 likes CDN due to security and not my path... altough it's odd since its from same domain... weird...